# 'Over' is preposition or adverb in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, subjects

I have a sentence here and hard to judge if it is a preposition or an adverb.

"Over 500 people were buried on the grounds."

In this sentence 'Over' is in the position of the subject. Would it be possible that a subject with preposition comes together like this?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to answer this using a dictionary. [over](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/over_1). Look for a similar example.

Comment: It was helpful. I found a similar example there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The primary "subject" is ***people***. Which you could think of as being "adjectivally" modified by ***over 500***, as it would be with, say, ***Many** people were buried here*.

Comment: Traditional grammars regard *over* as a preposition when it's followed by a noun phrase and an adverb when it is used on it's own. However, modern grammarians usually treat *over* as a prepositions whether or not it is followed by a noun phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *over* is a preposition here. It means *more than* a particular number. [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/over) has a very succinct explanation concerning this. They have also provided a few pertinent examples:

> **Over as a preposition**
>
> Over with numbers
>
> Over means 'more than' a particular number or limit.
>
> - *There were **over** 100 people at the lecture.*
> - *If your hand baggage weighs **over** 10 kilos, you must check it in.*
> - *She couldn't enter the competition. She was **over** the age limit.*

There's nothing wrong with a preposition being in that position; 'over 500' is a prepositional phrase functioning as determiner in the noun phrase 'over 500 people'.

Comment: "Over 500 people" is not a PP, but an NP with "people" as head and the PP "over 500" as determiner.

Comment: I prefer to think of it as "people" being a post-modifier of the quantity "over 500".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You mean 500 is the head? But it cannot stand alone.

Comment: @user178049:  The quantity can stand alone. Over 500 saw the spectacle that day. 500 saw the spectacle that day.  500 left the factory floor but were later recalled.  But we don't know 500 of *what* unless the context informs us or  an explicit noun is supplied.  "Seven remained" is a grammatical utterance; you could open a short story with it.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I would regard that a fused-head construction. Yes, in that case, you're right-it is the head (and also the dependent). But in this case, 'over 500 people', I would say it's just a normal noun phrase where *people* is head and *over 500* is the dependent.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo No, that's not the correct analysis. "Over 500 people" is a noun phrase in which "people" is head and the preposition phrase "over 500" is determiner. Nouns don't normally post-modify PPs, and in any case only PPs denoting places and time can be subjects.

Comment: @BillJ:  I don't take "over 500" as a PP. *Over ten is too many.*

Comment: Of course it's a PP - it has the preposition "over" as head! The cardinal number "500" is its complement, and the whole PP "over 500" functions as determiner in the NP "over 500 people".

Comment: @BillJ: *Over ten. Under ten. Exactly ten*.  Is **exactly** a preposition? You don't admit the possibility that **over** is a relative quantifier , 500 a quantity, and **people** a *complement* of the quantity, indicating what it is a quantity of?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo If you subscribe to the DP hypothesis, then you would regard the Determiner as the Head of the DP. But if you regard *a dog* as a noun phrase as opposed to a DP, then you would regard *people* as the Head of that phrase. You could go one way or the other. But DP people will never yield to NP people and vice versa.